Cover part of an axis with color
I need to color (in red in my example) part of the vertical axes: with the code below it does not work.
I think it must be a problem related to the "priority" because if I ask to draw an oblique line, it is displayed: it is only the coloring of part of the vertical axes that does not seem to be correct.
\documentclass[border=0.2cm,11pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\mathcode`\.="013B%virgule décimale en mode math
%\usepackage{tikz}% chargé automatiquement par pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={~},use comma}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
    
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[% mise en forme du graphique :
            xmin=-0.2,xmax=1.2,
            ymin=70,ymax=195,    % <<<
            samples = 100,
            no markers,
            ticks=none,
            hide x axis,
            hide y axis,
            ]
            % courbe calculée :
            
            \path[draw=red] (axis cs:0,97) -- (axis cs: 0,100);
            \path[draw=red] (axis cs:1,97) -- (axis cs: 1,175);
            %\addlegendentry{courbe d'ébullition};
            
            \addplot[mark=none] expression[domain=0:1]{97};
                    
            
            \draw[->] (axis cs: 0,80) -- (axis cs: 0,185)node[above]{A pur};
            \draw[->] (axis cs: 1,80) -- (axis cs: 1,185)node[above]{B pur};
            \draw[->] (axis cs: 0,80) -- (axis cs: 1.1,80);
            \draw[->] (axis cs: 0,80) -- (axis cs: 1.1,80) node[anchor=north west]{$x_B$};
            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


If you draw something on top, it gets hidden.
\documentclass[border=0.2cm,11pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\mathcode`\.="013B%virgule décimale en mode math
%\usepackage{tikz}% chargé automatiquement par pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={~},use comma}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
    
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[% mise en forme du graphique :
            xmin=-0.2,xmax=1.2,
            ymin=70,ymax=195,    % <<<
            samples = 100,
            no markers,
            ticks=none,
            hide x axis,
            hide y axis,
            ]
            % courbe calculée :
            

            %\addlegendentry{courbe d'ébullition};
            
            \addplot[mark=none] expression[domain=0:1]{97};
                    
            
            \draw[->] (axis cs: 0,80) -- (axis cs: 0,185)node[above]{A pur};
            \draw[->] (axis cs: 1,80) -- (axis cs: 1,185)node[above]{B pur};
            \draw[->] (axis cs: 0,80) -- (axis cs: 1.1,80);
            \draw[->] (axis cs: 0,80) -- (axis cs: 1.1,80) node[anchor=north west]{$x_B$};
            
            \path[draw=red] (axis cs:0,97) -- (axis cs: 0,100);
            \path[draw=red] (axis cs:1,97) -- (axis cs: 1,175);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

